# how to duplicate an audio stream in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, audio, stream, audio-recording, tonejs

I have toneJS playing various audio on a website and I want to record it.
If I connect the stream to a MediaRecorder it stops going to the speakers. I'm looking for a way to duplicate a stream so it can keep playing and record in the background.

Any advice?

(I'm taking a look at doing it manually with an AudioWorklet but I was hoping this is already implemented somewhere and I just haven't found it)

I tried audiocontext.createChannelSplitter but it's not working for this. The channels it creates can't be used as a stream as far as I can tell, its purpose is different.